# Promises in mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, promise

Can anyone please explain why this:

```
// this works
router.route('/videos')
  .get((req, res)=>{
    Video.find()
      .exec()
      .then(console.log);
  });

// this also works
router.route('/videos')
  .get((req, res)=>{
    Video.find()
      .exec()
      .then(videos=>{
        res.json(videos)
      });
  });
```

works, and this:

```
router.route('/videos')
  .get((req, res)=>{
    Video.find()
      .exec()
      .then(res.json);
  });
```

doesn't?

The `res` object represents the HTTP response that an Express.js app sends when it gets an HTTP request. The `console.log` method outputs the videos data while `res.json` does not seem to be called.

Comment: Are you losing an error due to the promises? Tap a .catch() on the end: `.then(res.json).catch(console.log);`

Comment: Try `.then(res.json.bind(res))`, as you might be losing the binding context.

Comment: This is about how `this` works, not promises, either bind or wrap it in a lambda

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Isn't this a duplicate? I just can't find it right now

Comment: It is, probably "how does this work in JavaScript", I'm on mobile

Comment: Thank you, res.json.bind(res) solved it. Sorry if it's duplicate.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Nah, I meant of another [promise] question that had this problem with express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.json` does expect to be called as a method, with `res` being the `this` value. It works with `console.log` because that is already bound to the `console` object in node.

You can use

```
.then(res.json.bind(res))
```

or continue to use that arrow function. See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)